# Powershell/Regex: Get 8 Characters after given String

Tags: regex, parsing, powershell

I have a Textfile containig

```
Random Text Test: abcd1234(/cxcd)
```

How do i extract the Random value after Test: with Powershell using Regex  I always need the 8 chars after "Test: "

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$text -match "Test: (.{8})"`

Your match is now in `$matches[1]`

http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebook/archive/2009/03/30/chapter-13-text-and-regular-expressions.aspx